# How to convert audio stream to .wav file and save

Tags: java, audio, streaming, wav

I am having some trouble figuring out how to convert audio data stream captured as 128 byte by a device to a .wav file and then how to save that .wav file. I am using eclipse with JRE8 to create a java project. Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
public void StartStreaming(){

{if(device !=null)}

{device.startAudioInput();}}


public void ConvertToWav()
{
//NEED HELP HERE
}

public void SaveWav()
{
//NEED HELP HERE TOO
}}
```

I have reviewed the tutorial on capturing sound but I cannot figure out how to convert the data to a .wav file and then save it.

I am not a coder by training so I would greatly appreciate if you could explain things as if you were talking to a beginner/non-coder/idiot. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you found so far? Have you looked in the documentation? Do some research of your own.

Comment: I am unclear by what you mean when you say 128 byte. Is the data signed PCM? Is it some sort of encoding? If so, how many bits per sound frame? And what is the number of frames per second? Is the data stereo or not? All this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy you could take:

1. Find a command line tool which can do the conversion for you.  The tool doesn't have to be written in java, but it can be executed from the command line (dos shell, bash shell, etc).  Try it from the command line first and make sure it works as you expect.  You'll have to research a little and find a tool which works for your purposes.  If this is going to run in production on a different operating system than your development computer, make sure the tool works in all OS.  Here's just one example.  I am not advocating it as I've never used it.  http://www.coolutils.com/CommandLine/TotalAudioConverter
2. You can invoke native commands from java, ie, the tool you just found in #1.  Warning, this is not beginner java programming.  However, it will accomplish your task.  Here's an example:http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/